# create a photoshop file or illustrator file using php

Tags: php, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Can we create photoshop file or illustrator file by using php?

I want to create a flash application that can perform simple position allocation with few type of shape, and those position and shape will be "convert" into photoshop file or illustrator file by php.

May i know is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator is easy enough because the EPS format is fairly standard and the core hasn't changed (the same can't be said of Photoshop).

However, I'm going to recommend that you look into Scalable Vector Graphics, which can also be read by Illustrator or Photoshop:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics

This is an XML based markup language and can do everything you want it to... and will be tons easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at creating a ps file using [php ps](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ps.php) or a pdf using [php pdf](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) either of these can be opened into illustrator readily and as far as photoshop you can generate images using [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [imageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Comment: And then there's the FPDF library: http://www.fpdf.org/ This library works very well and you can also use it for drawing graphics.

Answer (score 0):

echnically, it is possible to [output a native PSD file](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577409_pgfId-1054855). It's not a simple process, but the idea is you would use raw file writes to create the appropriate headers and file sections. There are reserved sections for the header, color mode, resources, layers/masks, and image data.

The complexity would be in piping data for an existing image into the data section and matching the specification. I'd need to look into the most similar format (ie. TIFF I'm assuming) for this section. It also needs to match the selected color space (RGB or CMYK).

The real benefit to PSD is the layering option. I'm interested in using existing PSD files, modifying existing data (ie. text in a smart object layer), and then rendering it. On the server-side, it's more efficient to use Photoshop droplets and hot folders to automate processing over creating a PSD library imo.

The other answer by John Green is a good recommendation -- to use a more open/interoperable file format. If you need to leverage layers, you'll need to get into the weeds or get a bit more creative outside of PHP.